# How to use xcopy to copy folders with same name from all partitions to a backup partition

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I have a folder repeated in all partitions, with the same name but different contents. I need to copy these folders to another partition in a few lines of code, but not once for each partition,  such as

```
Xcopy c:\userroot\storage G:\backup\
```

This would need to be repeated for many partitions: C D E F H I..... Many lines. Can't I condense these lines into one, or two at most?

Comment: You can use a `FOR` construct with variable substitution. I have never been able to wrap my head around Microsoft's `FOR` syntax, though. You will need to know the list of partitions you want to copy the directory to, but it should reduce what you want to do to a single command line.

Comment: Also, did you really mean to tag this *MS-DOS*? Because MS-DOS is a legacy operating system that hasn't been in common use for 20 years. Note that the command line of current Windows operating systems is very distinctly *not* MS-DOS.

Comment: Thanks Micheal but i searched in tag didn't find dos i found ms-dos

Comment: Could yoy please write example for a for command in this case.